# Exponential inequality $\exp(\frac{x+y}{2})\le \exp(x)+\exp(y)+\exp(x+y)$

Tags: inequality

Prove that

$$
\exp\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\le \exp(x)+\exp(y)+\exp(x+y),
$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. There an algebraic approach to prove this inequality. Maybe some calculus manipulations will lead to this inequality. I wonder if it is possible to avoid derivative or another analysis stuffs. My attempt was to factor the expresiion obtained after putting all terms on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convexity:
$$
\exp\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}\exp(x) + \frac{1}{2}\exp(y) \leq \exp(x) + \exp(y) \leq \exp(x) + \exp(y) + \exp(x+y)
$$
So your estimation is actually way to brutal.

Or more elementary: Use Young's inequality, i.e. $uv \leq \frac{u^2+v^2}{2}$ for real numbers $u, v$ (comes directly from $0\leq (u-v)^2$, just expand). It follows:
$$
\exp\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \exp\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{\exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\exp\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2}{2} = \frac{\exp(x)+\exp(y)}{2}
$$

Comment: Interesting application of Young inequality. I was hoping that this particular case would lead me to the solution of a general inequality that I have to prove. It is about $
\exp\left(  \left(  1-\lambda\right)  x+\lambda y\right)  \leq\left(
1+e^{x}\right)  ^{1-\lambda}\left(  1+e^{y}\right)  ^{\lambda}-1$, for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. It is possible to use Young inequality even in this general case?

Comment: For your follow-up question, use Jensen's inequality for the convex function $\log(1+e^x)$.

Comment: @TannySieben is right.  But first get $-1$ to the other side and apply $\log$ to both sides. I don't really think that Young will get you anywhere.

Comment: @Tanny Sieben Yes, you are right. But there is a way that I can prove that $y=\ln(1+e^x)$ is a convex function without using derivatives?

Comment: Pretty much impossible... Is it your task to not use derivatives?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=e^\frac x2$ and $b=e^\frac y2$, so that your desired inequality is $ab \leq a^2+b^2+a^2b^2$ for $a, b>0$. This is easy to show, e.g. by $$ ab \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} < a^2+b^2+a^2b^2 $$